# IPv6 local address in hosts file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ipv6, hosts-file

I have set up a local domain on my Apache server.

Then I added the following line in my `/etc/hosts` file

```
::1                     exampledomain.local
```

After I trying to navigate to it, (I tried Firefox and Chromium) I got a server not found error.

Then I tried `ping6` and it worked:

```
dan@danny:~$ ping6 exampledomain.local
PING exampledomain.local(exampledomain.local) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from exampledomain.local: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
```

If I replace `::1` with `127.0.0.1` in my hosts file, it works fine.
I'm not sure if this is relevant but this is my Virtual Host configuration in Apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias exampledomain.local
        DocumentRoot /home/dan/sites/exampledomain

        <Directory /home/dan/sites/exampledomain>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/exampledomain-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/exampledomain-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My question is: How can I make it work with the IPv6 address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ping it then there is nothing wrong in the hosts file and i would think its something to do with the Apache config.

- Check your Document root is correct and all the files are in correct place.
- This link here for [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) shows that the IPV6 must be in square brackets.
- Any firewalls/IPtables blocking IPV6 packets?

Bill

Comment: I changed `Listen 80` to `Listen *:80` it works now. That was very weird. I changed it back to Listen 80 it still works. I guess after Apache started, something must have been listening to the [::]:80 address. So Apache couldn't bind to it.

Comment: You just had to restart it as I think it picks up new /etc/hosts upon startup.